# Red asterisk after ng-required input (without label)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, required, ng-required

I'm looking for a CSS rule to apply a red asterisk after the inputs with the `ng-required` attribute.

The thing is, there is no label on those inputs, the placeholder is used as a label.

Those 2 inputs for instance :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="CACLastName" ng-model="cac.lastName" placeholder="NOM" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="$parent.isDisabled" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="CACFirstName" ng-model="cac.firstName" placeholder="Prénom" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="$parent.isDisabled" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I tried to play with `:after` but without success. Also, the `:required` only apply to the `required` attribute, not `ng-required`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use the :after pseudo-element on an input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field
It explains the reason why you can't do it on input elements, also there are a few ideas on how to wchieve it by adding additional elements, but you will have to crate your directive, or extend the ng-required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried CSS, and the selector does not seem to work at all for input elements while it will work for a div element.  You can try the following, and you will see that the asterisk is inserted after the `div` and not after the `input`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="CACLastName" ng-model="cac.lastName" placeholder="NOM" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="$parent.isDisabled" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" name="CACirstName" ng-model="cac.firstName" placeholder="Prénom" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="$parent.isDisabled" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="text-div" ng-required="true">
  TEST DIV LOOK -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[ng-required]:after {
  content: "*"
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

[Jsfiddle live example of problem](https://jsfiddle.net/67bb88gw/)

In my opinion this is a job for javascript.  With your html, this code will work (native JS):

```
var form_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')

for ( var i = 0; i < form_inputs.length; i ++ ) {
    if ( form_inputs[i].hasAttribute('ng-required') ) {
    form_inputs[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span style='color: red;'>*</span>');
  }
}
```

[Jsfiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/puhjs2wg/)

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me, isn't all clean I want, but here goes:

I wrap the element into a `<span>` with a `class="obligatorio"`. Then getting all them by ClassName, appending it a `div` with absolute position, "*" content => `textNode` and other item class properties.

So, I put an element over de fiels...

HTML

```
<span class="obligatorio"><input type="date" name="ingreso"></span>
<span class="obligatorio"><input type="time" name="lavIn"></span>
```

CSS

```
.obligatorio {
  position:relative;
}

.obligatorioItem {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top:2px;
  left: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Javascript Vanilla

```
var obligatorio = document.getElementsByClassName("obligatorio");

for (const element of obligatorio) {
    console.log(element);
    const nodo = document.createElement("div");
    nodo.classList.add("obligatorioItem");
    const texto = document.createTextNode("*");
    nodo.appendChild(texto);
    console.log("elemento:", element);
    element.appendChild(nodo);
}
```